# Issue with cropping large images with JCrop

Tags: jquery, jcrop, image-scaling, image-size

This plug-in works fine for smaller images but it does not crop correctly on large images.

My .preview_container is 250px by 153px. I believe I am doing something wrong in my "updateCoords" function as it may not be getting the coordinates based off the true image size.

Everything looks great in the preview when cropping, it's just saving the image with incorrect cropping.

Thanks in advance!

JS:

```
jQuery(function($){

// Create variables (in this scope) to hold the API and image size
var jcrop_api,
    boundx,
    boundy,

    // Grab some information about the preview pane
    $preview = $('#preview-pane'),
    $pcnt = $('#preview-pane .preview-container'),
    $pimg = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img'),

    xsize = $pcnt.width(),
    ysize = $pcnt.height();

console.log('init',[xsize,ysize]);


    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
  onChange: updatePreview,
  onSelect: updateCoords,
  aspectRatio: xsize / ysize
},function(){
  // Use the API to get the real image size
  var bounds = this.getBounds();
  boundx = bounds[0];
  boundy = bounds[1];
  // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
  jcrop_api = this;

  // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
  $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);
});


function updatePreview(c)
    {
      if (parseInt(c.w) > 0)
      {
        var rx = xsize / c.w;
        var ry = ysize / c.h;

        console.log('update',[c.x,c.y]);

        $pimg.css({
          width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
          height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
          marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
          marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
        });
      }
    };


  function updateCoords(c)
  {
    $('#x').val(c.x);
    $('#y').val(c.y);
    $('#w').val(c.w);
    $('#h').val(c.h);
  };

  function checkCoords()
  {
    if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
    alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
    return false;
  };    

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using html2canvas to capture the image in the preview div and save it as a PNG.